How should I present completed pen testing simulations on resume and LinkedIn if I plan on staying in a defensive security role?
My career in cybersecurity of 11 years have all been in defensive (blue team) roles to date. I plan on staying in a blue team role for forseeable future and do not intend to formally move to a pen testing role.
As a hobby related to my work, I have:

Completed pen testing simulations on Hackthebox.com virtual machines and gained significant experience even though I am not a pen tester

Written walkthroughs I host on a personal blog and post to Youtube for these exercises

Written and released a module to automate the exploitation of a vulnerability for the MetaSploit framework, widely used by offensive security (red team) professionals.

Submitted a code pull request to an open source tool used by cyber professionals that was accepted and merged.


Tools I developed proficiency in using include Bloodhound, Mimikatz, BurpSuite, MetaSploit Framework among others.
I feel these hobbies would add value to my resume and LinkedIn profile as they show technical expertise in the cyber field, dedication to learning, resourcefulness in use of industry tools, and efforts to give back to the cybersecurity profession. However, as I am in a blue role, I am hesitant as these skills are not directly related to my day job.

For a defensive security professional, should I include these hobbies?

What's the best format to present them on LinkedIn such as recorded YouTube videos, links to blog posts etc.?

Is there any reason for concern that my "red team" hobbies could scare employers focused on blue team services?



A bit of context: I'm also an Information Security Professional, but with a different background. I'm currently working in a more blue team-ish position after spending several years on the offensive side.

For a defensive security professional, should I include these hobbies?

I would definately list this in my resumee. Not only does this demonstrate your passion for the field, it also adds value to your blue team capabilities: You are not only able to defend your systems, you are also able to think like an attacker.

What's the best format to present them on LinkedIn such as recorded YouTube videos, links to blog posts etc.?

Regarding the best format, I guess that's up to you. I love it when I can read walkthroughs an writeups of hackthebox machines or other ctfs - but some times a video is also nice to watch. Do you already have Videos recorded? Then link them. Do you have a blog? Link it. Would I start recording videos, just to add them to linkedin? Probably not.
Did you complete one of the HTB Certifications or a Pro Lab? You could add these to your Linkedin as "Certifications".

Is there any reason for concern that my "red team" hobbies could scare employers focused on blue team services?

I don't see any reason to be concerned - as you already stated that your offensive security hobby takes place in a sanctioned environment for skilled professionals.

Halfway through the Dante pro lab and on CWEE certification.

@Anthony Not bad - I'm probably at the same spot in Dante, but paused my subsciption due to time constraints.
If you have unfinished certs, you could add them to your resumee with an estimated completion date.

These additional talents are worth noting on your resume.
Any company capable of hiring blue team, should understand the difference.
The company would be interested in the candidate's ethics and any reason to be concerned.
Better to list the information than they find your PR (for a red test) during a background check. Maybe they wouldn't find it, maybe they would. If they did, it would raise questions if you didn't bring it up first.

Several pen test simulations required reverse engineering of compiled applications. Is reverse engineering of apps likely to scare employers?

IMHO and that is IMHO pen testing employment is about being able to trust the employee as much as the skillset. The employee must learn to be valuable. Getting that training via legitimate sources and being honest about it is meaningful during the hiring process.

@Anthony - You can reverse engineer compiled applications to also build a defense. You have 10 years in your field. We do not. You know your industry best.

@Anthony I have no specialised cybersecurity experience, but in my software development experience, companies are not worried about employees reverse engineering their products at all.

Thinking about some more. Consider not referring to "Red Team Hobbies". These are either community events or self-study. You can say this with a straight face because it is true. Just because you had fun doesn't mean there wasn't value to your career.
